# Running a bot in a specified channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been working on a 24/7 trivia bot, and I've gotten a pretty 'eh' version out to the public. I'm trying to get it to only send in one channel, that is specified in my code. But, that will not be a good strategy when in multiple servers.

```
async def trivia_loop(self):
    channel = self.client.get_channel(ID_RETRACTED)
    if not channel:
      return
```

It does its job very well, for the one channel I have specified. But as stated it simply does not work for channels that not have been added by a dev. Could I use a database? Or maybe making it look for a channels name rather than its ID?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why would it not be a good strategy when in multiple servers?
Maybe if you want to send things in the system channel the guild obj has a system channel object to get the system channel for the guild.
On the other hand, you can search for keywords in guild channels. For example, if the channel has the word 'bot', you can do `guild.channels` and find if there are any channels with bot.
A simple admin command that sends a message to the channel in **all** server that contains the word 'commands'

```py
async def broadcast(ctx,*,message):
    for chan in client.get_all_channels():
        if "commands" in chan.name:
            await chan.send(message)
```

Another Example...
If you only want to send it in 1 server per guild and in system channel

```py
async def broadcast(ctx,*,message):
    for guild in client.guilds:
        #Make sure you have permissions to send in system channel
        await guild.system_channel.send(message)
```